# how to build a runnable jar file in intelliji 14.1.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

i'm having issues in creating a runnable jar file using the intelliji EDK, i have tried this before in the Eclipse EDK and it was a succes, yet i don't seem to find any luck with this one.

Comment: What did you try? You need to configure an artifact in the Project Structure dialog.

Comment: yes sir i did try it and i couldn't go any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to create a .jar using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4:

```
1.File > Save All.
2.Run driver or class with main method.
3.File > Project Structure.Select Tab "Artifacts".
4.Click green plus button near top of window.
5.Select JAR from Add drop down menu. 
6.Select "From modules with dependencies"Select main class. 
7.The radio button should be selecting "extract to the target JAR." 
8.Press OK.Check the box "Build on make"Press apply and OK.
9.From the main menu, select the build dropdown.
10.Select the option build artifacts.
```